# css - vertical align image inside a div with max-width/max-height/overflow hidden?

Tags: css, overflow

I have several div's with images in my articles, I'm cropping the images using max-width/height and overflow:hidden which works great, however it's cropping images from the top and I'd like them to be vertically centered in the div.

```
.image_div {
    max-height: 150px; 
    max-width:99%; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin:0px; 
    text-align:center;
}
.image_div img {

}
```

I'm using max-width/height to avoid having a big block of whitepsace in case the image is small. Is what I'm looking for possible with css?

Should also mention a CSS3 solution would be great as well since this is a mobile site.

Comment: Have you considered resizing the images as opposed to cropping them?  If you simply set a height/width in your `.image_div img` css rule, it should resize the image for you without cropping.

Comment: Problem is these images are coming from feeds without width/height specified, and the images vary in sizes fromm 100x100 to 800x800, so a css solution to center an image vertical/horizontal inside a cropped div would be fantastic.

Comment: setting a width/height for the css would distort them if their aspect ratios aren't the same.

Comment: The aspect ratio comment is true - you would have to do something in javascript where you get the actual height/width and then make sure to preserve the ratio when you resize.  Pick your poison.

Comment: What about setting the image as the background image and using background position `center center`?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but may provide a supplementary tool to the project you're working on, but I'd consider looking into timthumb: http://code.google.com/p/timthumb/.  It's a very handy php library/plugin which allows you to crop and scale images.

Comment: True, while waiting for an answer here I hacked up a simple solution in jQuery. I didn't even think about using a background image position Jrod, thanks for that!

Comment: @Mike - I did consider downloading the images from the feeds then use imagemagick to build thumbs, not practical at this point but it is something we'll be doing down the road to improve page load speed.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
.imgsquare {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 2px;
    border: solid 1px #666;
    background-color: #333;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.imgsquare * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.imgsquare {
    display: block;
}
.imgsquare span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 1px;
}
</style>

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style>
.imgsquare span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

this draws a square div with a vertical / horizontal centered image in origin aspect ratio 
using:

```
<div class="imgsquare" style="width:280px; height:280px;">
    <span></span>
    <img style="max-width:260px; max-height:260px;" src="yourPicture.jpg" alt="No Image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just use vertical align like so:

```
.image_div {
    max-height: 150px; 
    max-width:99%; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin:0px; 
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:text-top;
}
```

You can change the 'text-top' to a number of things, w3c lists them here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp